# Sending data via JSON from Android to PHP web service using HttpUrlConnection

Tags: php, android, json, web-services, urlconnection

I'm currently developing an Android application for a small project which consists in learning development on Android platform. I already did all the app and now I need to send data from the app to a server in PHP with MySQL database. I have a web service to make the insert in the database from data sent through a json format. I have tested the web service with Advanced Rest Client and I have succeeded in inserting data into my database. Now I'm testing from my android app application but it doesn't work. I have checked the connection status and it is "OK" but when I check the database, there is no insertion.

Below is my web service in PHP:

```
<?php  

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);
$con = mysql_connect('host','login','password') 
   or die('Cannot connect to the DB');
mysql_select_db('database_name',$con);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `commercial` (firstName, surNameC, email, number, salonName, uuid)
VALUES ('".$obj->{'firstname'}."','".$obj->{'name'}."','".$obj->  {'email'}."','".$obj->{'phonenumber'}."','".$obj->{'fairreference'}."','".$obj-> {'commercialuuid'}."')");
mysql_close($con);

$posts = "INSERTION OK";
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('posts'=>$posts)); 

?>
```

And the sending process from the android side:

```
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
    StringBuilder strBuilder;
    try {
        url = new URL(URL);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        urlConnection.connect();

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("commercialuuid", args[0]);
        jsonObject.put("name", args[1]);
        jsonObject.put("firstname", args[2]);
        jsonObject.put("phonenumber", args[3]);
        jsonObject.put("email", args[4]);
        jsonObject.put("fairreference", args[5]);

        Log.d("json", jsonObject.toString());
        Log.d("request", "starting");

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new   OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        writer.write(jsonObject.toString());
        writer.flush();

        Log.e("connection status",urlConnection.getResponseMessage());

        //get the response from the web service
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            strBuilder.append(line);
        }
        writer.close();
        reader.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
        return null;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

As I have searched for several threads that have been validated and based my work on it, I really don't understand why it doesn't work. 
I would be grateful if anyone could help me.

Thanks.

Comment: As a first step, capture the result of `mysql_query()`, take a look at this: https://github.com/dmnugent80/ShareAppServerSide/blob/master/databaseInsert.php

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I did it, it is quite useful. Now I have some advancement, I insert but there are no values in the inserted object.

Comment: I have printed the json I receive in the web service and it is empty. So, the problem is the way I send the json to the web service. Is there another way that using outputstreamwriter ? Because I checked the json on Logcat and it is well created and formatted.

Comment: Problem solved! It was totally from the free server I was using... buyethost... I have tested it on a local wamp server and I works!

Answer (score 2):

**-->Update:
As the comments say, this answer is now deprecated and your only choice is to use the lib Retrofit, im using it now without problems. look for it and i recomend using Retrofit2 instead of the older one.||**

You can use $post to send your just de data you want to insert

insert it into a thread or an async task

```
List<NameValuePair> querypair=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();;
                        querypair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));
                        querypair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                        querypair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
                        HttpPost httpGetquery =new HttpPost("http://www.youradddres/insert.php");
                        httpGetquery.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(querypair));
                        HttpResponse httpResponseGetQuery = httpClient.execute(httpGetquery);
                        httpEntityQueryGet = httpResponseGetQuery.getEntity();
                        Log.i("Entity",httpEntityQueryGet.toString());
```

also upload this php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "dbname";

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","$username","$password");
mysql_select_db("$dbname", $con);

$id=$_POST['id'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table(id, name, email)
VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$email')");

echo "New record created successfully";

?>
```

hope it helps

Comment: also your DBuser must have privileges to do inserts!

Comment: `DefaultHttpClient` and `BasicNameValuePair` are deprecated in api 22, and removed in api 23.

Comment: Yes indeed. And now is the trend of JSON to manipulate data between platforms